# pgfplots: setlength inside foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, loops

I have the following code, where the size of the cube marks is set to `\x` inside a `foreach` loop:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=none]
  \newlength{\mylen}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,10} {
  \setlength{\mylen}{\x pt}
    \addplot3[only marks,scatter,mark=cube*,mark size=\mylen] coordinates {(\x*5,10*\x,3*\x)};
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This results in an empty plot - i.e. it doesn't work.

However, if we set the length for `mylen` (to a constant) *before* the foreach-loop, it works just fine. That might be a clue. Any ideas?

Also, how can can I manipulate the length inside the `\setlength` command to for instance `\setlength{\mylen}{2*\x+10 pt}` ?

Comment: The assignment works for me inside the loop. Please post a minimal example which demonstrates the problem. Also you have `…` in it not `...` which is an unicode character. Are you doing anything special? (special package, Xelatex, ...).

Comment: @Martin: I have posted a new example, that hopefully clarifies my problem. I tried it in a MWE and I didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{list}{command}` command for this, instead of the usual `\foreach`. That makes sure the parameter is passed to the `\addplot` options expanded, so when the plots are actually drawn (which does not happen immediately, I believe), they include the correct parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=none]
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,...,10} {
    \addplot3[only marks,scatter,mark=cube*,mark size=#1 pt] coordinates {(#1*5,10*#1,3*#1)};
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, ok. I wonder why the `\addplot` command isn't defined in a way that expands it options and stores the expanded values instead.

Comment: @Martin,Jake: This works just fine, but there is a problem. Setting `mark size=#1+10` works while setting `cube/size x=#1+10pt` does not (it does however without the `+10pt`). Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Milosz: You must add the unit (pt) to both numbers or not have any units. You can't mix this two styles in PGF/TikZ. So either use `mark size=#1pt+10pt` or `mark size=#1+10` (then the default unit is used, which is normally 1cm and way to large).

Comment: @Martin: Nope, that doesn't do the trick. It does for `mark size` but not for `cube/size x=#1pt+10pt`. It seems as the size expands to only the first argument, so for instance `cube/size x=#1pt+10pt` expands to `cube/size x=#1pt` while `cube/size x=10pt+#1pt` expands to `cube/size x=10pt`.

Comment: @Milosz: It depends how the values are parsed by `pgfplots`, i.e. if `\pgfmathparse` is used or not. Try to write it as `\the\dimexpr #1pt+10pt\relax`. This handles the addition in eTeX and is expandable.

Comment: @Martin: That did it. Is there a way I can multiply `#1` with a fraction? I tried `\real{0.3}` using the `calc` package with no result.

Comment: @Milosz: use `0.3\dimexpr#1\relax`. If you get an PGFmath error wrap the whole expression in `\the\dimexpr ... \relax`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the `\addplot` command doesn't interpret its options when it is encountered but only afterwards when the plot is drawn.
This means that the current value of `\x` or `\mylen` inside the loop is not used but the latest value before or after it. The loop content is executed inside a group, so that changes don't survive afterwards.

In your case all plots where drawn using `mark size=\mylen` with `\mylen` having the default value of 0pt. The solution is to expand the value manually beforehand and call `\addplot` with the expanded value. You actually don't need the length for this. If you want to use it exchange `\x` with `\the\mylen` in the `\edef` part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=none]
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,10} {
        \edef\PLOT{\noexpand\addplot3[only marks,scatter,mark=cube*,mark size=\x pt]}
        \PLOT coordinates {(\x*5,10*\x,3*\x)};
    };
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Next time PLEASE provide a full compilable, but minimal example. I never used `pgfplots` before and had to guess the preamble. Here it turned out to be pretty simple but it can be quite complicated with PGF/TikZ when many libraries are required.