# Numbers as markers with \foreach and additional macro based on counter

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach, graphs

**First issue**

I would like to plot several curves using the `\foreach` command and
have their number in the sequence as markers.
Here is the code I came up with :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread{
1 4   0.2  0.1
2 4.2 0.1  0.5
3 3.1 0.3  0.4
4 2.5 0.25 0.35
}\table

\begin{axis}
  \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
\addplot+[text mark={\i}, mark=text] table[x index=0, y index=\i]{\table};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and here is the result it raises :
[image]

My problem is that for some reason the `text mark={\i}` is stuck to
`1`.

A solution is to use the `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` command (see my answer).

**Second issue**

But now if I need some other index computed from the counter using for instance

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{\i+1}% with the \foreach command
```

I would write

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{##1+1}% with the \pgfplotsinvokeforeach command
```

but this last one does not work. I think the problem is that the `#1` is interpreted as if it is supposed to represend an argument of `\pgfmathsetmacro`. My attempt of doubling the hash did not solve this second issue.

Comment: Have you tried a counter and the stepcounter function?

Comment: No. I will have to read about this command though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the updated problem you can use the math engine of PGF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread{
1 4   0.2  0.1
2 4.2 0.1  0.5
3 3.1 0.3  0.4
4 2.5 0.25 0.35
}\table

\begin{axis}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3}{%
\addplot+[text mark={\pgfmathparse{int(#1+1)}\pgfmathresult}, mark=text] table[x index=0, y index=#1]{\table};};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thanks.
Do you know a general method to avoid getting `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmath@expression.` errors?

Comment: @AlfredM. Unfortunately the cause depends on the context however usually due to a wrong argument number and/or using `#1` in a non argument expecting macro.

Comment: What I meant is : is there a way to prevent the #1 inside a nested macro definition to be intrepreted as an argument of the *inside* macro instead of the argument of the *outside* one?
I thought doubling the hash (`##1`) was doing this but apparently not.

Comment: @AlfredM. It might be more complicated than that since expansion inside `foreach` problematic enough and partially solved via `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`. I don't know what the actual problem you have is but you can always ask a question specific to this such that you have more space to fully explain it. Follow-ups are more than welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be solved by using `\pgfplotsforeach` instead of `\foreach`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread{
1 4   0.2  0.1
2 4.2 0.1  0.5
3 3.1 0.3  0.4
4 2.5 0.25 0.35
}\table

\begin{axis}
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3}{%
\addplot+[text mark={#1}, mark=text] table[x index=0, y index=#1]{\table};};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I found it thanks to this question [pgfplots: setlength inside foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14131/pgfplots-setlength-inside-foreach).